# Head First Design Patterns question on Duck Simulator walk through in chapter 1

Tags: design-patterns, code-reuse

I am having trouble reconciling a walk through example in intro to design patterns chapter. I copied several images of the chapter's assertion, solution, and apparent contradictions.

Problem: Joe was berated for having rubber ducks flying around on his simulator. He eventually proposes "How about an interface?" There, the MallordDuck (and others) are declared as children of the Duck class and implement one or more interfaces.

[image: Joe's proposal to use an Interface]

For which he is again berated by the lady supervisor who asks "how are going to feel when you have to make a change to the flying behavior in all 48 duck classes?" The text to the right of the supervisor asserts that it completely destroys code reuse for those behaviors

[image: Destroys code reuse]

And in the programming to an interface solution the UML illustration appears to require same amount of duplicate code that Joe was berated for. It doesn't seem to solve that problem. The only way I can think of to do so is to put the most used implementation for fly() and Quack() into the interface (which isn't possible in Java - I guess) and may be something you don't want to do even if were possible. In addition it seems that they are also hidden behind the interface...

[image: UML diagram illustrating programming to an interface]

Well I've either overthought this too much or I just don't understand the assertions of code duplicatation and "these behaviors are no longer hidden away in our Duck classes"

Any clarification or further explanations are greatly appreciated.

thank you
Kial

Answer (score 3):

The pattern that you have described in the above code is based on design principle: "Encapsulate what varies".

The author in the book is trying to emphasize the fact that when you use inheritance, it can create a lots and lots of subclasses in case if there is a new functionality to be added in the system. Instead you can delegate the responsibility of the behavior that may change over time like in our case fly and quack behaviors to other classes that may be defined at run time.

For example, when you use inheritance, suppose you have to create n ducks, n*4 classes are required, say

```
Duck + fly + quack
Duck + not fly + not quack
Duck + fly + not quack
Duck + not fly + quack

Rubber duck - 4 classes like above
Mallard duck - 4 classes like above
Baby Duck - 4 classes like above.

For n ducks n*4 duck classes are required.
```

Instead using composition or using below two interfaces.

```
Flyable -> 2 classes fly and not fly 
Quackable -> 2 classes quack and not quack 
Duck -> 1 Duck class with above Flyable and Quackable.

With above structure, for n different type of ducks n+4 classes are required.
```

Answer (score 1):

The approach taken by Head First is to identify those methods in superclass (in this case Duck) which are frequently overridden by its subclasses (RubberDuck, DecoyDuck). In your example, quack() and fly() are frequently overridden methods.

The authors then pulls out all those methods (superclass and subclass) and pushes each of them into its own class. Classes that implement variations of a particular behavior (i.e quack) are then united under a interface whose name is descriptive of the group's behavior (this group has classes which describe how a duck can quack (or not) and this group has classes which describe different flying behaviors)

I believe the answer to your question is that a duck will now **delegate** its flying or quacking behaviors to one of those behavioral classes. The code is no longer needs to be duplicated by two or more different duck types. In other words, you now have ducks sharing code instead of each hosting its own. This was the nightmare that Joe's supervisor was referring to.

Answer (score 0):

> And in the programming to an interface solution the UML illustration appears to require same amount of duplicate code that Joe was berated for. It doesn't seem to solve that 
>   problem.

That's right. Inheritance (by subclassing or using interfaces) is pretty inflexible to changes, which is what the managers are trying to explain.

> Well I've either overthought this too much or I just don't understand the assertions of code duplicatation and "these behaviors are no longer hidden away in our Duck classes"

They're pulled out of the implementations of Duck classes, and put into a new hierarchy of *Behavior* classes. Then the Duck classes can (as needed) use the implementations of those behaviors (think of plug-ins).

The basic idea is to favor composition over inheritance, because composition is more flexible to change and allows more re-use. **HAS-A can be better than IS-A** (read that section).

[image]

Instead of each Duck class having its own implementation of `fly()` or `quack()`, it's going to reuse one of the 4 behaviors (which could be extended later if need be) that have been encapsulated separately. Each Duck *has a* behavior, again like a plug-in it can use. With this approach, you can even have a duck *change* its behavior at run time, by re-assigning its definition.

```
quackBehavior = /* choose a new implementation */
```

There's another (funny) explanation with JavaScript, but I like the idea of chaotic change, and how inheritance can be a bad solution: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wfMtDGfHWpA